# Open a shell script from other script and close the first

Tags: shell

I want to know how to call a script from another script ( I know it ) but also, close the first script process that remains in background.

I use this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

#script

echo "first script"
./ second.sh
```

when I do this, the first script remains in background, and, when I close the second script with an EXIT command, it returns to the first script.

Answer (score 1):

Use `exec`:

```
exec second.sh
```

This completely replaces the original shell (script) with the new one.

The notation `./` won't work; you can't execute the current directory.  If you were thinking of `. second.sh`, that reads the new script into the current script.  If you were thinking of `./second.sh`, then you need to write `exec ./second.sh`.

Strictly, the first script is not in the background; it is simply waiting for the executed program (which happens to be the second shell script) to finish.  'In the background' has specific connotations of 'running', whereas the first script is not actively running when you run `second.sh`.